# Eclipse RCP application using Java web start not starting up

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jnlp, java-web-start

I am attempting to run an Eclipse RCP application using Java Web Start. However, I encounter this error after the application is downloaded and run:

JNLP JREDesc in Component ignored: null

After that, the application closes. What is the workaround for this?

This is my main JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/demoui-webstart/" href="start.jnlp"> 
  <information> 
    <title> Demo UI Application </title>  
    <vendor>Me</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.me.org" />
    <description>description</description> 
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>

  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"/>
    <extension name="Wrapper feature" href="features/org.test.webstart.demo.wrapperfeature_0.1.0.jnlp"/>

    <property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/demoui-rcp"/>
    <property name="osgi.configuration.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/demoui-rcp"/>

    <property name="eclipse.application" value="org.test.webstart.demo.plugin.application"/>
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
    <argument>-nosplash</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

org.test.webstart.demo.wrapperfeature_0.1.0.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/demoui-webstart/">
    <information>
        <title>Wrapperfeature</title>
        <vendor>Me</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"/>
        <extension href="features/org.test.webstart.demo.feature_0.1.0.jnlp" />
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

org.test.webstart.demo.feature_0.1.0.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/demoui-webstart/">
    <information>
        <title>Feature</title>
        <vendor>Me</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
        <jar href="plugins/org.test.webstart.demo.plugin_0.1.0.jar"/>
        <extension href="features/org.eclipse.rcp_3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272.jnlp" />
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

org.eclipse.rcp_3.7.2.v20120120-1424-9DB5FmnFq5JCf1UA38R-kz0S0272

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/demoui-webstart/">
    <information>
        <title>Eclipse RCP</title>
        <vendor>Eclipse.org</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <component-desc/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" />
    </resources>
    <resources>
        <jar href="plugins/com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110823.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.0.I20110111-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.0.I20110111-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.0.I20110222-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.0.I20110222-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.2.100.I20100824-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.101.v20120113-1953.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.300.v20110228.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20110110.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.0.v20110513.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.help_3.5.100.v20110426.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.5.0.I20100907-0800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7.1.v20120104-1859.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.carbon_4.0.100.I20101109-0800.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.ui.cocoa_1.1.0.I20101109-0800.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.100.v20100512.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="s390x">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="s390">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Solaris" arch="sparc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Solaris" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="AIX" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="AIX" arch="ppc64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="HP-UX" arch="ia64_32">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32_3.7.2.v3740f.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.rcp_3.7.2.v201202080800.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20110321.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.3.1.R37x_v20110701.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.300.v20110502.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.4.2.v20120111-2020.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.101.R37x_v20110810-1611.jar"/>
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Solaris" arch="sparc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.sparc_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Solaris" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.x86_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="ppc64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc64_1.0.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="s390x">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.s390x_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="s390">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.s390_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="AIX" arch="ppc">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc_1.1.0.v20110530.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="AIX" arch="ppc64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc64_1.1.0.v20110530.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502.jar"/>
    </resources>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: I tried JaNeLA and the JNLP was without errors. Still, the application cannot start.

Comment: That information does not gel with *"JREDesc in Component ignored:"*  What component (extension) JNLPs are used?  What is their content?

Comment: Basically, I have three JNLPs apart from the main JNLP. Two feature projects (Eclipse RCP) and another one generated by Eclipse RCP.

Comment: *"I tried JaNeLA and the JNLP was without errors."*  Which 'JaNeLA' are *you* looking at?  I see errors for that JNLP when I load it in JaNeLA.  A couple of them are due to the missing `component-desc` but at least one is apparent even from eye-balling the edited text of the JNLP.  Also, you mention 3 extensions, while that JNLP only lists one.  Where are the other 2 listed?

Comment: I have attached the other JNLP files.

Comment: Thanks for the full details, but there is still a problem with the first JNLP, and at least one of the extensions (you can check it more easily there).  The main problem I get here is `cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'resources'. No child element is expected at this point.`  The [JaNeLA help](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html#error) explains *"..cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found .. most often means that elements are out of the correct order in the launch file. ..try shifting the element further up the document."*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for pointing those errors out. I fixed them by rearranging the elements but the problem persists.

Comment: OK.  So their are **no** red/pink errors left in the output?  Make sure you uninstall the app. & extensions before trying with a new JNLP.  JWS updates Jars well, but can cache (& not update) JNLP launch files to a frustrating extent.

Comment: Yes. There are no more red/pink errors. I have also made sure the files were not cached.

Answer (score 1):

1.7 is not production ready yet.  It could be you've uncovered a bug in the implementation.

---

> JNLP JREDesc in Component ignored: null

This is because of the declaration of:

```
 <j2se version="1.7+" />
```

In each extension.  By the time an extension is loaded, the JRE has been chosen and is running, it is up to the version specified in the *main launch file* to ensure the right version for the app. (& all extensions).

I actually find that frustrating in that it would be an easy way to indicate the minimum version required, to users of the extension.  OTOH you can make it a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues about this problem (i had the same):

- "JNLP JREDesc in Component ignored: null" is just an information, not a problem. Its shown when multiple jnlp files declare a j2se version. The first one is taken.
- If webstart is closing, this is probably due to a different error. Try to figure out the error in the following way: Open the file **$HOME/.java/deployment/deployment.properties** and set **deployment.javaws.logToFile=true** and **deployment.javaws.logFileName=LOG_FILE**. Restart your webstart application and then read your log file **LOG_FILE** in order to view the actual problem the console couldn't show (because it closed to fast).
- Then, it is also possible, that even if the webstart meachnism works fine, your eclipse RCP application does not. In this case your LOG_FILE shows no problem, but regard in the directory, specified with "**osgi.instance.area**" in your jnlp file. Look there for **.metadata/.log** file or any other log file. You should then try to solve the eclipse rcp problems, if there are any shown in those log files.
- By the way, in may case I tried an Eclipse RCP 4 application. To get run an RCP 4 application with Webstart, you must add the following property to your main jnlp file (under the resources tag) to ensure, that some important plugins are loaded in a consistent way:

  ```
  <property name="osgi.bundles"
       value="org.eclipse.core.runtime@4:start,
              org.eclipse.equinox.common@3:start,
              org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2:start,org.
              eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator@1:start">
  ```